# Having trouble with regex

Tags: c#, regex

Can somebody tell me what regex I would need to filter out ---> %, &, ! <---- I know the basic word tests, but not some of the special characters.

Comment: (1) What language are you using? (2) What do you mean by "filter out"? Is your goal to convert `3% ab` to `3 ab`, or is your goal to give some sort of error message if you get `3 % ab`, or is your goal something else?

Comment: I am using .NET C# and I am looking to convert 3% ab 3 ab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just write:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, "[%&!]");
```

The brackets `[...]` denote a character class, meaning "any one of these characters".

Answer (score 0):

Or... you could just do the following:

```
String testValue = "3% ab";

testValue = testValue.Replace("%",String.Empty);
```

Comment: Yes, but then I would have to have a separate replace for each character. Thus why I was looking for the Regex solution